# Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Tomcat Stop Run

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

Apache Tomcat Server 9.0.19 Not Start.
I created new project and include the tomcat but not start and giving this error

```
08-May-2019 23:18:03.205 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1383)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Some solutions at below, which prev questions on stackoverflow

- restart tomcat
- delete caches
- enter to vm option this : "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

but still doesn't work.

can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

You should try deleting existing deployed war from webapps of tomcat and try redeploying a fresh war. It seems your any of the existing application has same packaging details which are conflicting with your new project.

Clear those wars ( and there directories ) from webapps which are not required.

Comment: i removed the apache and download again and include to project, and i did select redeploy, but still same error.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this @ErdemSiyam

Comment: @TinasheChinyanga i just deleted everything about java and tomcat, than re-install all of these last versions.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem with me. I just deleted(not un-installed) the old tomcat and installed new tomcat with same version on the same directory as before. Worked perfectly for me.